# How to manage different layout on Configuration Changed in activity for foldable android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, foldable-devices

Created a demo for foldable devices. When the device is folded, I want to show one layout and when the device is unfolded I have different layout to show.then how to manage two layout according to Configuration Changed.?

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        Log.i(myTag, "onConfigurationChanged...")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set callbacks to receive states: CLOSED, HALF, OPEN.

```
private fun setFoldableCallbacks() {
        mainThreadExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
        windowManager = WindowManager(this, null)
        windowManager.registerDeviceStateChangeCallback(
            mainThreadExecutor,
            deviceStateChangeCallback
        )
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            windowManager.registerLayoutChangeCallback(mainThreadExecutor, layoutChangeCallback)
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please also share deviceStateChangeCallback ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `onConfigurationChanged` method you should use [Jetpack WindowManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/foldables#foldable_modes) as explained by @user3471194. But keep in mind that [its API has changed](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/window) quite a bit, so with version `1.0.0-alpha05` WindowManager's constructor might have only one parameter (activity). Also I recommend to declare activity's configChanges in Manifest file as follows

```
<activity
        ...
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation|smallestScreenSize">
        ...
</activity>
```

On the other hand, the callback you pass to `registerLayoutChangeCallback` method no longer retrieves a `DeviceState` object but a `WindowLayoutInfo` instead, which has `FoldingFeature` that might be set as `STATE_FLAT`, `STATE_FLIPPED`,`STATE_HALF_OPENED` etc or it will be null if the device is non-foldable.

Answer (score -1):

```
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
          setcontentview();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            setcontentview();
}
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: here the ORIENTATION is not protrait or landscape.i want for fold and unfold configration change